# XSLT repeating element

Tags: xml, excel, xslt

When exporting an XML feed in excel, the `<IMAGES>` repeating element is in the wrong format. Please help out how to get the right output.

Bad XML Output

```
<DATA>
    <CODE>1</CODE>
    <IMAGES>
        <IMAGE>1</IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
</DATA>
<DATA>
    <CODE>1</CODE>
    <IMAGES>
        <IMAGE>2</IMAGE>
    </IMAGES>
</DATA>
```

Correct XML Output

```
<DATA>
    <CODE>
        <IMAGES>
            <IMAGE>1</IMAGE>
            <IMAGE>2</IMAGE>
        </IMAGES>
    </CODE>
</DATA>
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Comment: you can use [Muenchian Method](http://www.jenitennison.com/xslt/grouping/muenchian.html) for grouping in `xslt 1.0` or `xsl:for-each-group` for later version

Comment: If there is an XSLT, then it would help if you showed it in your question (as code, not an image). A sample of your input XML (as code) would help also. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

For **XSLT 2.0** you can use *for-each-group*

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each-group select="DATA" group-by="CODE">
        <DATA>
            <CODE><xsl:value-of select="CODE"/></CODE>
            <IMAGES>
                <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()//IMAGE"></xsl:copy-of>
            </IMAGES>
        </DATA>
    </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

and for **XSLT 1.0** you can use *Muenchian Method*

```
<xsl:key name="datakey" match="DATA" use="CODE"/>
<xsl:template match="root">
    <xsl:for-each select="DATA[generate-id(.) = generate-id(key('datakey', CODE))]">
        <DATA>
            <CODE><xsl:value-of select="CODE"/></CODE>
            <IMAGES>
                <xsl:for-each select="//IMAGES[../CODE = current()/CODE]">
                <xsl:copy-of select="IMAGE"></xsl:copy-of>
                </xsl:for-each>
            </IMAGES>
        </DATA>
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:template>
```

Both script are convert this **Output**

```
<DATA>
   <CODE>1</CODE>
   <IMAGES>
      <IMAGE>1</IMAGE>
      <IMAGE>2</IMAGE>
   </IMAGES>
</DATA>
```